# R subset filterout specific dates from vector

Tags: r, filter, subset

Hello i have big problem with R
I have data like this:

```
df:

Dates        unique ID
20180101     10
20180101     20
20180101     18
20180201     34
20180101     10
...
20180330     10
```

I have about 1kk rows with unique id of specific client login. Its around 600 rows a day . But i want to filterout or subset only specific dates.

so i have created

```
id_list = c(20180101,20180102)
```

Then i have tried to subset:

```
 df = subset(df,df$Dates == id_list)
```

But my new df has missing values like each 2nd one is missing.
I know in this exapple i can do

```
df = subset(df,df$Dates == 20180101|20180330)
```

I want to do this with bigger list of about 50 dates in id_list.

Comment: Use `df = subset(df,df$Dates %in% id_list)`

Comment: Im really noob :) Thats works for me big thanks !